# Mongoose Find Fullname with array of String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Example Data

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b77a707ee4b1c14fcf43ff8"),
    "nombre" : "NICOLAS SEGUNDO ZULETA VELIZ",
    "nacimiento" : "10-09-1937",
    "difuncion" : "10-01-1995",
    "idPropiedad" : ObjectId("5b77a707ee4b1c14fcf43ff7"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to make a search where the follwoing search query would work on the Nombre property

```
nico zu
nicolas zuleta
nicolas segundo zuleta
zuleta veliz
zuleta nicolas
```

I have tried several stuff like

```
db.getCollection('difuntos').find({nombre: {$regex:"nico zu","$options": "i"}})
db.getCollection('difuntos').find({nombre: {$in : [ /nicolas/i,/zu/i ]}})
```

this wont work

Answer (score 0):

You can probably split your input (Eg. nico zu) into 2 elements -> [nico, zu] and the simply create a regex of this sort :

```
db.getCollection('difuntos').find({nombre: {$regex:".*nico.*zu.*","$options": "i"}})
```

All you need to do is surround your input words (eg. noco, zu) with (.*)

Comment: Even though that does work with the first options it would work with zuleta nicolas combination, and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
db.difuntos.find({"nombre": { $regex: searchString.split(' ').join("|"), $options: "i" }})
```

where `searchString` would be one of your example values:

```
nico zu
nicolas zuleta
nicolas segundo zuleta
zuleta veliz
zuleta nicolas
```